EnumOutputsでIDXGIOutputが取得できません。
DirectX12でD3D12Fullscreenのコードを参考にプログラムを作成していたところ、
自身のプロジェクトでは、「pSwapChain->GetContainingOutput(&pOutput)」で「IDXGIOutput」が取得できませんでした。
サンプルのプロジェクトでは、問題なく取得できました。
動作環境は、Windows11でGPUが「Intel Iris Xe Graphics」と「NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 Laptop GPU」が搭載されたノートPCを利用しています。
サンプルプロジェクトで取得できた「IDXGIAdapter1」は「NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 Laptop GPU」でした。
そこで、下記コードをサンプルプルジェクトと自身のプロジェクトで実行したところ、サンプルでは問題なく取得できましたが、自身のプロジェクトでは取得できませんでした。
HRESULTの戻り値は「0x887a0002」でした。
サンプルでは「int main()」で動くように設定を変えています。
サンプルと、通常のプロジェクトでは違う何かをしているのか、要因をご教示お願いいたします。
「Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022」で、Win32のプロジェクトで作成しています。
#include <dxgi1_6.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    IDXGIFactory6* factory;
    IDXGIAdapter1* adapter;
    IDXGIOutput* output;

    if (SUCCEEDED(CreateDXGIFactory1(IID_PPV_ARGS(&factory))))
    {
        if (SUCCEEDED(factory->EnumAdapterByGpuPreference(0, DXGI_GPU_PREFERENCE_HIGH_PERFORMANCE, IID_PPV_ARGS(&adapter))))
        {
            DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC1 desc{};
            adapter->GetDesc1(&desc);
            wcout << desc.Description << endl;
            auto hr = adapter->EnumOutputs(0, &output);
            wcout << "HRESULT: 0x" << hex << hr << endl;
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                DXGI_OUTPUT_DESC desc;
                output->GetDesc(&desc);
                output->Release();
            }
            adapter->Release();
        }
        factory->Release();
    }
}


「取得できませんでした」「失敗します」を具体的に、どのようなコードを実行し、どのような応答・エラーが発生したのかを説明してください。

エラーコード0x887A0002はDXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUNDに相当します。IDXGIAdapter::EnumOutputs()がインデックス0に対してこのエラーを返すということは、そのアダプター (GPU) がディスプレイに接続されていないということです。

DXGI_ERROR (Winerror.h) - Win32 apps | Microsoft Learn

マルチGPU環境では、ディスプレイがすべてのグラフィックスデバイスによって所有されているとは限りません。ノートPCのマルチGPU環境 (AMD Switchable Graphics / NVIDIA Optimus) の場合、ディスプレイは通常CPU内蔵GPU (iGPU) に所有されていて、GeForceのような単体GPU (dGPU) はオンボードであっても直結していないはず。
下記のChuck Walbourn氏のコメントを参照してください。ちなみに氏はMSのDirectXスペシャリストです。

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/184304/why-cant-i-create-a-d3d12-device-with-the-highest-performance-adpater-retrieved#comment330522_184305

なお、Direct3D 12のサンプルでは、すべてCreateDXGIFactory2()を最初に使っているはず。
一応Windows 7互換のCreateDXGIFactory1()も使えるのかもしれませんが、このファクトリ関数を使う場合はDXGIのデバッグ機能が使えません。

https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Desktop/D3D12Fullscreen/src/D3D12Fullscreen.cpp
https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Desktop/D3D12xGPU/src/D3D12xGPU.cpp


回答ありがとうございます。「CreateDXGIFactory2」を使用していることと何か関係があるのでしょうか？また、サンプル「D3D12Fullscreen」では「IDXGIOutput」が取得できています。自身のプロジェクトとサンプルのプロジェクトで何か違いがあるのでしょうか？ご教示お願いいたします。
